# After installing Magento2.4.6-p2 CSS and JS 404 not found

Tags: javascript, css, 404, .htaccess, magento2.4.6

I installed magento2.4.6-p2 in my C:\xampp\htdocs\magento2.
But I can see this.
[image]

In pub .htaccess file is :

```
############################################
## Optional override of deployment mode. We recommend you use the
## command bin/magento deploy:mode:set to switch modes instead

# Options are default, production, or developer
#   SetEnv MAGE_MODE default

############################################
## Uncomment these lines for CGI mode.
## Make sure to specify the correct cgi php binary file name
## it might be /cgi-bin/php-cgi

#    Action php5-cgi /cgi-bin/php5-cgi
#    AddHandler php5-cgi .php

############################################
## GoDaddy specific options

#   Options -MultiViews

## You might also need to add this line to php.ini
##     cgi.fix_pathinfo = 1
## If it still doesn't work, rename php.ini to php5.ini

############################################
## Enable usage of methods arguments in backtrace

    #SetEnv MAGE_DEBUG_SHOW_ARGS 1

############################################
## This line is specific for 1and1 hosting

    #AddType x-mapp-php5 .php
    #AddHandler x-mapp-php5 .php

############################################
## Default index file

    DirectoryIndex index.php

<IfModule mod_php7.c>
############################################
## Adjust memory limit

    php_value memory_limit 756M
    php_value max_execution_time 18000

############################################
## Disable automatic session start
## before autoload was initialized

    php_flag session.auto_start off

############################################
## Enable resulting html compression

    #php_flag zlib.output_compression on

###########################################
# Disable user agent verification to not break multiple image upload

    php_flag suhosin.session.cryptua off
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_php.c>
############################################
## Adjust memory limit

    php_value memory_limit 756M
    php_value max_execution_time 18000

############################################
## Disable automatic session start
## before autoload was initialized

    php_flag session.auto_start off

############################################
## Enable resulting html compression

    #php_flag zlib.output_compression on
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_security.c>
###########################################
# Disable POST processing to not break multiple image upload

    SecFilterEngine Off
    SecFilterScanPOST Off
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_deflate.c>

############################################
## Enable apache served files compression
## http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#gzip

    # Insert filter on all content
    ###SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
    # Insert filter on selected content types only
    #AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/plain text/xml text/css text/javascript application/javascript application/x-javascript application/json image/svg+xml

    # Netscape 4.x has some problems...
    #BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html

    # Netscape 4.06-4.08 have some more problems
    #BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip

    # MSIE masquerades as Netscape, but it is fine
    #BrowserMatch \bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html

    # Don't compress images
    #SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI \.(?:gif|jpe?g|png)$ no-gzip dont-vary

    # Make sure proxies don't deliver the wrong content
    #Header append Vary User-Agent env=!dont-vary

</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_ssl.c>

############################################
## Make HTTPS env vars available for CGI mode

    SSLOptions StdEnvVars

</IfModule>

############################################
## Workaround for Apache 2.4.6 CentOS build when working via ProxyPassMatch with HHVM (or any other)
## Please, set it on virtual host configuration level

##    SetEnvIf Authorization "(.*)" HTTP_AUTHORIZATION=$1
############################################

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

############################################
## Enable rewrites

    Options +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine on

############################################
## You can put here your magento root folder
## path relative to web root

    #RewriteBase /magento/

############################################
## Workaround for HTTP authorization
## in CGI environment

    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

############################################
## TRACE and TRACK HTTP methods disabled to prevent XSS attacks

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^TRAC[EK]
    RewriteRule .* - [L,R=405]

############################################
## Redirect for mobile user agents

    #RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/mobiledirectoryhere/.*$
    #RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "android|blackberry|ipad|iphone|ipod|iemobile|opera mobile|palmos|webos|googlebot-mobile" [NC]
    #RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /mobiledirectoryhere/ [L,R=302]

############################################
## Never rewrite for existing files, directories and links

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

############################################
## Rewrite everything else to index.php

    RewriteRule .* index.php [L]

</IfModule>


############################################
## Prevent character encoding issues from server overrides
## If you still have problems, use the second line instead

    AddDefaultCharset Off
    #AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
    AddType 'text/html; charset=UTF-8' html

<IfModule mod_expires.c>

############################################
## Add default Expires header
## http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#expires

    ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType text/html A0
    ExpiresByType text/plain A0

</IfModule>

###########################################
## Deny access to release notes to prevent disclosure of the installed Magento version

    <Files RELEASE_NOTES.txt>
        <IfVersion < 2.4>
            order allow,deny
            deny from all
        </IfVersion>
        <IfVersion >= 2.4>
            Require all denied
        </IfVersion>
    </Files>
    <Files .htaccess>
        <IfVersion < 2.4>
            order allow,deny
            deny from all
        </IfVersion>
        <IfVersion >= 2.4>
            Require all denied
        </IfVersion>
    </Files>
## Deny access  to cron.php
    <Files cron.php>
        <IfVersion < 2.4>
            order allow,deny
            deny from all
        </IfVersion>
        <IfVersion >= 2.4>
            Require all denied
        </IfVersion>
    </Files>
## Deny access  to .user.ini
    <Files .user.ini>
        <IfVersion < 2.4>
            order allow,deny
            deny from all
        </IfVersion>
        <IfVersion >= 2.4>
            Require all denied
        </IfVersion>
    </Files>

# For 404s and 403s that aren't handled by the application, show plain 404 response
ErrorDocument 404 /errors/404.php
ErrorDocument 403 /errors/404.php

################################
## If running in cluster environment, uncomment this
## http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#etags

    #FileETag none

# ######################################################################
# # INTERNET EXPLORER                                                  #
# ######################################################################

# ----------------------------------------------------------------------
# | Document modes                                                     |
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------

# Force Internet Explorer 8/9/10 to render pages in the highest mode
# available in the various cases when it may not.
#
# https://hsivonen.fi/doctype/#ie8
#
# (!) Starting with Internet Explorer 11, document modes are deprecated.
# If your business still relies on older web apps and services that were
# designed for older versions of Internet Explorer, you might want to
# consider enabling `Enterprise Mode` throughout your company.
#
# https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/bg182625.aspx#docmode
# http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2014/04/02/stay-up-to-date-with-enterprise-mode-for-internet-explorer-11.aspx

<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    ############################################
    Header set X-UA-Compatible "IE=edge"

    # `mod_headers` cannot match based on the content-type, however,
    # the `X-UA-Compatible` response header should be send only for
    # HTML documents and not for the other resources.
    <FilesMatch "\.(appcache|atom|bbaw|bmp|crx|css|cur|eot|f4[abpv]|flv|geojson|gif|htc|ico|jpe?g|js|json(ld)?|m4[av]|manifest|map|mp4|oex|og[agv]|opus|otf|pdf|png|rdf|rss|safariextz|svgz?|swf|topojson|tt[cf]|txt|vcard|vcf|vtt|webapp|web[mp]|webmanifest|woff2?|xloc|xml|xpi)$">
        Header unset X-UA-Compatible
    </FilesMatch>

    ## Prevent clickjacking
    Header set X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN
</IfModule>
```

In pub/stactic .htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_php5.c>
php_flag engine 0
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_php7.c>
php_flag engine 0
</IfModule>

# To avoid situation when web server automatically adds extension to path
Options -MultiViews

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    ## you can put here your pub/static folder path relative to web root
    #RewriteBase /magento/pub/static/

    # Remove signature of the static files that is used to overcome the browser cache
    RewriteRule ^version.+?/(.+)$ $1 [L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

    RewriteRule .* ../static.php?resource=$0 [L]
    # Detects if moxieplayer request with uri params and redirects to uri without params
    <Files moxieplayer.swf>
        RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^$
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %{REQUEST_URI}? [R=301,L]
     </Files>
</IfModule>

############################################
## setting MIME types

# JavaScript
AddType application/javascript js jsonp
AddType application/json json

# HTML

AddType text/html html

# CSS
AddType text/css css

# Images and icons
AddType image/x-icon ico
AddType image/gif gif
AddType image/png png
AddType image/jpeg jpg
AddType image/jpeg jpeg

# SVG
AddType image/svg+xml svg

# Fonts
AddType application/vnd.ms-fontobject eot
AddType application/x-font-ttf ttf
AddType application/x-font-otf otf
AddType application/x-font-woff woff
AddType application/font-woff2 woff2

# Flash
AddType application/x-shockwave-flash swf

# Archives and exports
AddType application/zip gzip
AddType application/x-gzip gz gzip
AddType application/x-bzip2 bz2
AddType text/csv csv
AddType application/xml xml

<IfModule mod_headers.c>

    <FilesMatch .*\.(ico|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|svg|js|css|swf|eot|ttf|otf|woff|woff2|json)$>
        Header append Cache-Control public
    </FilesMatch>

    <FilesMatch .*\.(zip|gz|gzip|bz2|csv|xml)$>
        Header append Cache-Control no-store
    </FilesMatch>

</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_expires.c>

############################################
## Add default Expires header
## http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#expires

    ExpiresActive On

    # Data
    <FilesMatch \.(zip|gz|gzip|bz2|csv|xml)$>
        ExpiresDefault "access plus 0 seconds"
    </FilesMatch>
    ExpiresByType text/xml "access plus 0 seconds"
    ExpiresByType text/csv "access plus 0 seconds"
    ExpiresByType application/json "access plus 0 seconds"
    ExpiresByType application/zip "access plus 0 seconds"
    ExpiresByType application/x-gzip "access plus 0 seconds"
    ExpiresByType application/x-bzip2 "access plus 0 seconds"

    # CSS, JavaScript, html
    <FilesMatch \.(css|js|html|json)$>
        ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 year"
    </FilesMatch>
    ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType text/html "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType application/json "access plus 1 year"

    # Favicon, images, flash
    <FilesMatch \.(ico|gif|png|jpg|jpeg|swf|svg)$>
        ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 year"
    </FilesMatch>
    ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType image/svg+xml "access plus 1 year"

    # Fonts
    <FilesMatch \.(eot|ttf|otf|svg|woff|woff2)$>
        ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 year"
    </FilesMatch>
    ExpiresByType application/vnd.ms-fontobject "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType application/x-font-ttf "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType application/x-font-otf "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType application/x-font-woff "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType application/font-woff2 "access plus 1 year"

</IfModule>
```

Which file should I change? How should I change?

I need someone help.

Thanks

=== UPDATE ===
I run command like that:

```
php bin/magento config:set dev/static/sign 0
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
php bin/magento cache:clear
```

if I go to localhost/magento2/pub, show this page

[image]

if I go to signup or login page

[image]

What is this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not quite sure how's your apache configuration, but maybe you can try to remove versioning number in those js/css static files.

How to remove versioning number?

1. execute this sql command into your database: *(this will remove your versionining number)*

```
insert into core_config_data (config_id, scope, scope_id, path, value) values (null, 'default', 0, 'dev/static/sign', 0);
```

> You can also execute `php bin/magento config:set dev/static/sign 0` from your magento directory path

2. Once you've been executed that command, try to execute:

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
php bin/magento cache:clean
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! I got home page, but I cannot find login and other pages. what is the reason?

Comment: please to leave more detail about this one, screenshots included are better

Answer (score 1):

Run this command on your server

```
php bin/magento config:set dev/static/sign 0
```

Clear the cache

```
php bin/magento cache:clean
```

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same problem after wasting lot of time  solved it just adding the .htaccess file in root folder in godaddy hosting.

.htacess code

```
############################################
## overrides deployment configuration mode value
## use command bin/magento deploy:mode:set to switch modes

#   SetEnv MAGE_MODE developer

############################################
## uncomment these lines for CGI mode
## make sure to specify the correct cgi php binary file name
## it might be /cgi-bin/php-cgi

#    Action php5-cgi /cgi-bin/php5-cgi
#    AddHandler php5-cgi .php

############################################
## GoDaddy specific options

#   Options -MultiViews

## you might also need to add this line to php.ini
##     cgi.fix_pathinfo = 1
## if it still doesn't work, rename php.ini to php5.ini

############################################
## this line is specific for 1and1 hosting

    #AddType x-mapp-php5 .php
    #AddHandler x-mapp-php5 .php

############################################
## default index file

    DirectoryIndex index.php

<IfModule mod_php5.c>

############################################
## adjust memory limit

    php_value memory_limit 768M
    php_value max_execution_time 18000

############################################
## disable automatic session start
## before autoload was initialized

    php_flag session.auto_start off

############################################
## enable resulting html compression

    #php_flag zlib.output_compression on

###########################################
## disable user agent verification to not break multiple image upload

    php_flag suhosin.session.cryptua off

</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_php7.c>

############################################
## adjust memory limit

    php_value memory_limit 768M
    php_value max_execution_time 18000

############################################
## disable automatic session start
## before autoload was initialized

    php_flag session.auto_start off

############################################
## enable resulting html compression

    #php_flag zlib.output_compression on

###########################################
## disable user agent verification to not break multiple image upload

    php_flag suhosin.session.cryptua off

</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_security.c>
###########################################
## disable POST processing to not break multiple image upload

    SecFilterEngine Off
    SecFilterScanPOST Off
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_deflate.c>

############################################
## enable apache served files compression
## http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#gzip

    # Insert filter on all content
    ###SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
    # Insert filter on selected content types only
    #AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/plain text/xml text/css text/javascript

    # Netscape 4.x has some problems...
    #BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html

    # Netscape 4.06-4.08 have some more problems
    #BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip

    # MSIE masquerades as Netscape, but it is fine
    #BrowserMatch \bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html

    # Don't compress images
    #SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI \.(?:gif|jpe?g|png)$ no-gzip dont-vary

    # Make sure proxies don't deliver the wrong content
    #Header append Vary User-Agent env=!dont-vary

</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_ssl.c>

############################################
## make HTTPS env vars available for CGI mode

    SSLOptions StdEnvVars

</IfModule>

############################################
## workaround for Apache 2.4.6 CentOS build when working via ProxyPassMatch with HHVM (or any other)
## Please, set it on virtual host configuration level

##    SetEnvIf Authorization "(.*)" HTTP_AUTHORIZATION=$1
############################################

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

############################################
## enable rewrites

    Options +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine on

############################################
## you can put here your magento root folder
## path relative to web root

    #RewriteBase /magento/

############################################
## workaround for HTTP authorization
## in CGI environment

    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

############################################
## TRACE and TRACK HTTP methods disabled to prevent XSS attacks

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^TRAC[EK]
    RewriteRule .* - [L,R=405]

############################################
## redirect for mobile user agents

    #RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/mobiledirectoryhere/.*$
    #RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "android|blackberry|ipad|iphone|ipod|iemobile|opera mobile|palmos|webos|googlebot-mobile" [NC]
    #RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /mobiledirectoryhere/ [L,R=302]

############################################
## never rewrite for existing files, directories and links

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

############################################
## rewrite everything else to index.php

    RewriteRule .* index.php [L]

</IfModule>


############################################
## Prevent character encoding issues from server overrides
## If you still have problems, use the second line instead

    AddDefaultCharset Off
    #AddDefaultCharset UTF-8

<IfModule mod_expires.c>

############################################
## Add default Expires header
## http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#expires

    ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType text/html A0
    ExpiresByType text/plain A0

</IfModule>

###########################################
## Deny access to root files to hide sensitive application information
    RedirectMatch 404 /\.git

    <Files composer.json>
        order allow,deny
        deny from all
    </Files>
    <Files composer.lock>
        order allow,deny
        deny from all
    </Files>
    <Files .gitignore>
        order allow,deny
        deny from all
    </Files>
    <Files .htaccess>
        order allow,deny
        deny from all
    </Files>
    <Files .htaccess.sample>
        order allow,deny
        deny from all
    </Files>
    <Files .php_cs>
        order allow,deny
        deny from all
    </Files>
    <Files .travis.yml>
        order allow,deny
        deny from all
    </Files>
    <Files CHANGELOG.md>
        order allow,deny
        deny from all
    </Files>
    <Files CONTRIBUTING.md>
        order allow,deny
        deny from all
    </Files>
    <Files CONTRIBUTOR_LICENSE_AGREEMENT.html>
        order allow,deny
        deny from all
    </Files>
    <Files COPYING.txt>
        order allow,deny
        deny from all
    </Files>
    <Files Gruntfile.js>
        order allow,deny
        deny from all
    </Files>
    <Files LICENSE.txt>
        order allow,deny
        deny from all
    </Files>
    <Files LICENSE_AFL.txt>
        order allow,deny
        deny from all
    </Files>
    <Files nginx.conf.sample>
        order allow,deny
        deny from all
    </Files>
    <Files package.json>
        order allow,deny
        deny from all
    </Files>
    <Files php.ini.sample>
        order allow,deny
        deny from all
    </Files>
    <Files README.md>
        order allow,deny
        deny from all
    </Files>

################################
## If running in cluster environment, uncomment this
## http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#etags

    #FileETag none

############################################
## Add custom headers
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff"
    Header set X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block"
</IfModule>
```